why ANSI color code in c affects next line?
i created a simple library in c to outout colored text in the console
you can find the code on github: https://github.com/bocchitherockk/io_styler
this is the demo code
#include <stdio.h>
#include "io_styler.h"

int main() {
    char *message = "Hello, how are you!\n";
    c_printf((char* []) { BG_WHITE, FG_BLUE, ST_BOLD, NULL }, message);
    c_printf((char* []) { FG_RED, ST_BOLD, NULL }, message);
    c_printf((char* []) { FG_BLUE, NULL }, message);
    c_printf((char* []) { ST_BOLD, FG_RED, FG_BLUE, NULL }, message);
    return 0;
}

the problem is when i run the code the first time, it works fine, the second and third time without clearing my terminal works also fine, but the forth time an extra white background gets printed in the next line

keep in mind that this happens when i don't clear my terminal, when i do, this behaviour resets and does the same thing the forth time i run the code
At first i was doing something wrong, and i tried to fflush stdin and stdout in multiple different places but nothing seems to solve it, i also looked for other libraries on github and i tried them and they had the exact same issue
what could be the problem ? and is there any solutions to it ?

It's probably a duplicate because most of the duplicates are FAQs, but is dealt with in depth here
